# What to put into lat/lng db fields if lat/lng are empty?

Tags: mysql, sql, geolocation

I have a mysql insert statement that breaks when the system can't get lat/lng for a user.
The sql loos like this:

```
INSERT INTO users(user_email, first_name , last_name , lat , lng ) values ( 'name'
 , 'email' ,  ,  );
```

What should I put into the lat/lng so that it doesn't break the insert statement like this? Should it be nulls? That seems kind of inappropriate to put nulls, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Null is allowed if the table definition allows it. Null lat/long might mean that the user's location is unknown